# Spinorial representation of Lorentz group for solution to Dirac equation

Tags: representation-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

In my relativistic quantum mechanics course, we found plane wave solution to the Dirac equation by first studying it the reference frame of the particle. Using a plane wave solution for both positive and negative energy we got

$$
(i\not \partial -m)u(m,0)e^{-ip_\mu x^\mu} = 0 \implies (\not P - m)u(m,0) = (\gamma^0-1)u(m,0)=0
$$

for the positive energy solution. Then we evaluated the negative energy solution in the same way to get, in the end

$$
u(m,0) = \alpha \left(
\begin{matrix}
1\\0\\0\\0
\end{matrix} \right) + \beta \left(
\begin{matrix}
0\\1\\0\\0
\end{matrix} \right) = \alpha u^{(1)}(m,0)+\beta u^{(2)}(m,0) \\
v(m,0) = \alpha^\prime \left(
\begin{matrix}
0\\0\\1\\0
\end{matrix} \right) + \beta^\prime \left(
\begin{matrix}
0\\0\\0\\1
\end{matrix} \right) = \alpha v^{(1)}(m,0)+\beta v^{(2)}(m,0)
$$

Then to get the general solution we had to do a Lorentz transformation: at this point the professor said something that it's not so clear to me. I quote

> Since $(\not P -m)(\not P +m)=0$ we can easily do a reference frame transformation such that 
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{matrix}
> u^{(\alpha)} = c_{\alpha}(\not P +m)u^{(\alpha)}(m,0)\\
> v^{(\alpha)} = d_{\alpha}(\not P -m)v^{(\alpha)}(m,0)
> \end{matrix}
> \right.
> $$

so, leaving the normalisation factors behind for a moment, he's implying that the representation of a general Lorentz transformation for the spinor components of the Dirac spinor (note that I'm working in standard, non chiral, representation) are given by $(\not P-m)$ and $(\not P +m)$. It is clear why the first statement is useful: so that when we plug in the solutions made in this way they are in fact solution to the Dirac equation. My question then is

> How can this be proven?

Probably it would be easy to prove it in chiral representation, but even still I'm not able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Lorentz transformation of the spinor parametrizing by the matrix $S$:
$$
u(\mathbf p) \to S u(\mathbf{0})
$$
Here $S$ corresponds to the Lorentz transformation $\Lambda_{\mu}^{\nu}p_{\nu,\text{rest}} = p_{\mu}$, where $p_{\nu,\text{rest}} = (m,\mathbf{0})$ and $p_{\mu} = (E,\mathbf{p})$. $\gamma$ matrices have a property
$$
S^{-1}\gamma_{\mu}S = \Lambda_{\mu}^{\ \nu}\gamma_{\nu},
$$
using which we obtain
$$
\tag 1 \color{red}{\gamma_{\mu}p^{\mu}S =} S\Lambda_{\mu}^{\ \nu}p^{\mu}\gamma_{\nu} = S(\Lambda^{-1} p)^{\nu}\gamma_{\nu} = \color{red}{mS\gamma_{0}}
$$
This property is failed to satisfy if $S \propto \gamma_{\mu}p^{\mu}+m$ as far as $\gamma_{0} \neq \mathbb{1}$. The latter is impossible.